# Recursively find the path & location of a value in a list

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion, arraylist

I am working on parsing huge nested JSON files, (sometimes the file size is bigger than 25MB) using [ESPRIMA](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html)'s [library for Python](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/pyjsparser). I have a problem in finding the location of the values in lists in the JSON file.

Here is the small simplified example of the JSON file:

```
parsed = {
    "type": "Program",
    "body": [
        {
        },
        {
            "type": "ExpressionStatement",
            "expression": {
                "type": "CallExpression",
                "callee": {
                    "type": "MemberExpression",
                    "computed": "false",
                    "object": {
                        "type": "Identifier",
                        "name": "localStorage"
                    },
                    "property": [
                        {
                            "a": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Identifier"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "getItem",
                                    "property": [
                                        {
                                            "b": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "getItem"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "getItem"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Identifier",
                            "name": "getItem"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Identifier"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Identifier",
                            "name": "abcd"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Identifier",
                            "name": "getItem"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "arguments": [
                    {
                        "type": "Literal",
                        "value": "myCat0",
                        "raw": "'myCat0'"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    ],
    "sourceType": "script"
}
```

The function I use is the the following:

```
result_k = []
path_k = []
x = z = 0

def get_keys(dic, target):
    global x, z
    try:
        if isinstance(dic, list) and dic:
            for d in dic:
                get_keys(d, target)
                z += 1
        else:
            for key, value in dic.items():
                path_k.append(key)
                if isinstance(value, list) and not value:
                    pass
                elif isinstance(value, list) and value:
                    for v in value:
                        path_k.append(x)
                        get_keys(v, target)
                        x += 1
                        path_k.pop()
                    x = 0
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    get_keys(value, target)
                if value == target:
                    result_k.append(z)
                    result_k.append(copy(path_k))
                path_k.pop()
    except Exception as err:
        print('\x1b[1;37;41m{}\x1b[0m'.format(str(err)))
        traceback.print_exc()
```

and here is the output which is incorrect when it comes to the after-first-level-list; both incorrect locations are highlighted in the result (after **b**):

```
[
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'property', 1, 'b', **1**, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'property', 1, 'b', **2**, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 1, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 4, 'name']
]
```

**UPDATE 1:**
while the expected result is the following.

```
[
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'property', 1, 'b', **0**, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'property', 1, 'b', **1**, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 1, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 4, 'name']
]
```

I think the problem occurs because of the repetition of checking if the list is `dict` or `list` in the lines `if isinstance(dic, list):` and dic and `elif isinstance(value, list) and value:`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @MohitMotwani [
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'property', 1, 'b', 0, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'property', 1, 'b', 1, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 0, 'a', 1, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 1, 'name'], 
1, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', 4, 'name']
]

Comment: Post it in your question, too unclear to read in comments.

Comment: @MohitMotwani done. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: what's 1, 0 , 4 and **4** in your output?

Comment: They are the position of them in the list. For example when you arrive to an array then you need to know the position of it to be able to use it in the future. I added the position of the next step of my answer to the array.

now, ['expression', 'callee', 'property', **1**, 'name'] means that for reaching "getItem" you need to follow this path:
parsed['body'][0]['expression']['callee']['property'][1]['name']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177802/discussion-between-ali-and-mohit-motwani).